# displaying a canvas at two positions simultaneously

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

In C#, using WPF components, Is it possible to display a canvas (whose contents change at run time based on user input) at two positions on the screen? or in two windows? So basically, whatever happens in the canvas positioned at one place happens in the canvas positioned in the other place.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need them both to be interactive?

If not, then you could use a VisualBrush to duplicate the Canvas to another location. The VisualBrush part won't be interactive, but it will mirror what happens on the other one.

Comment: Seems pretty much close to what I want. How can I use a VisualBrush for it? Say canvasA is rendered in canvasB, and it needs to be rendered to canvasC as well...

Comment: Take a look at trimyeko's answer. There's an example in there for VisualBrush.

Answer (score 1):

So, there are 2 solutions :

1. create control containing your canvas & add them to required places and bind to your VM
2. use visualbrush as @Tim mentioned, example:

   ```
   <Window x:Class="visualbrushmirroringstackoverflow.MainWindow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

   <Window.Resources>
       <VisualBrush x:Key="MirrorBrush" 
            Visual="{Binding ElementName=TargetCanvas}" TileMode="None" 
            Stretch="None" AutoLayoutContent="False"/>
   </Window.Resources>
   <StackPanel>
       <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Add Random Rects" Margin="5"/>

       <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="5">
           <Canvas x:Name="TargetCanvas" Width="100" Height="100" 
                   Background="White" />
       </Border>

       <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="5">
           <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" 
                      Fill="{StaticResource MirrorBrush}" />
       </Border>
   </StackPanel>
   ```

handler in code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    var element = new Rectangle { Fill = Brushes.Black, Width = 5, Height=5 };
    Canvas.SetLeft(element, rnd.Next(100));
    Canvas.SetTop(element, rnd.Next(100));
    TargetCanvas.Children.Add(element);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're populating and updating the Canvas through databinding, you can create a usercontrol that defines the Canvas and all of it's styles, templates etc and bind each instance of that usercontrol to the same source object. Even in different windows, because they are updating from the same object in memory they should appear synchronised.

Comment: Yeah, that's right choice if OP have mvvm app ;) I mentioned that as an option too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem where i was asked to display a canvas in other window while retaining the original canvas.

What i did and you can do is this:

Since a single child cannot have multiple parents so you can make a copy of your original by serializing them using `XamlReader.Save`.

Put this canvas in a ViewBox (so that it stretches to its parent). Set contents of new window as this ViewBox.

```
Canvas copycanvas = XamlReader.Parse(XamlWriter.Save(OriginalCanvas)) as Canvas;
ViewBox vb = new ViewBox() { Stretch.Uniform, Child = copyCanvas };
Windows newwin = new Window() { Content = vb };
newwin.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I think you meant to say serializing with XamlWriter.Save not XamlReader.Parse